# How can I achieve this Result with recyclerView and toolbar

Tags: android-recyclerview, toolbar

[I want to achieve this Result. A full screen recylcerview and a toolbar on top of the recyclerView at all times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dfCK.jpg)

[This is how my application looks. A full screen recylcerview but I can't put a toolbar on top of the recyclerView since it lags behind and recyclerView in front](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rc43D.jpg)

Mi xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:tag="@string/tagMain"
    tools:context=".fragments.MainItemFragment">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/top_controls_background"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:menu="@menu/options_movie"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/app_name"/>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/mainRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My adapter

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: HolderAdapter, position: Int) {

        val items = listItems[position]
        holder.miniature.layoutParams = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(dimension,dimension)
        holder.miniatureType.layoutParams= RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(dimension/4,dimension/4)
        if (items.mediaType==3){
            holder.miniatureType.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_movie_type)
        }else{
            holder.miniatureType.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_image_type)

        }
        Glide.with(holder.miniature.context)
            .load(items.uri)
            .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
            .transform(CenterCrop(),RoundedCorners(18))
            .override(dimension,dimension)
            .into(holder.miniature)
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{
            onClickListener(items)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add your code so we see what you already have and find the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and interest. I just uploaded my xml code, it's a layout with a recylcerview and what I want is to put a toolbar or something similar on top of the recyclerView and have it displayed at all times when going up and down in the recyclerView. and the problem was that if I put a toolbar on top of it, it would get behind the recyclerView when swiping. and another fact is that my recyclerView is full screen

Comment: Do you want your RecyclerView to be fullscreen? Or is it wrong? Or do you mean it is going under system bars?